# How can i integrate magento 1.7.0 and magento 1.7.2

Tags: magento

i have compared files of magento 1.7.2 and my project in 1.7.0 and overwrite new files

but my question is that how can i merge my database into magento1.7.2 database

`catalog_category_flat_store_1` , `catalog_product_flat_1`

these 2 tables are present in my project - magento 1.7.0 but not exists in magento1.7.2

how how can i merge database

thanks in advance

Comment: i had backup but tables are different

Comment: then restore the backup and use the upgrade feature.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no Magento 1.7.2. The current version is 1.7.0.2.
2. This type of operation is not an "integration". Your database will be upgraded in-place after overwriting the 1.7.0.0 files with the new version files, clearing the cache, and browsing any page.